# How do I mount a Mac thumb drive on a Linux system?

Tags: mount, macintosh

When I insert a FAT thumb drive in a USB port it automagicly mounts. When I do the same thing with a thumb drive from a Mac system it does not show up in my file manager.

How do I mount a Mac thumb drive on a Linux system?

Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-28-generic (i686)
Desktop Environment: LXDE (Lubuntu)
Distribution: Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: What's the format on the Mac thumb drive? If it's an hfsplus formatted disk, Linux will refuse to mount it unless the format is explicit.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write does not refer to a USB device.